# PHP Insert HTML markup in the middle of other markup without breaking it

Tags: php, string

I am trying to embed a contact form (..) globally inside my wordpress posts without breaking the post's markup.

Say I have this code:

```
$str = 'My post text here my post text here<ul>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text2</li>
</ul> more text';
```

I have a PHP code which inserts text in the middle of `$str` (or `post_content` in our case), but how can I make sure I am not breaking the  code although its considered in the middle? I hope my questions is clear.

I'll give more details: I am trying to add a php code which inserts some html markup into wordpress posts in my blog. the thing is, that in some posts its just fine but in other posts it breaks the html code (incase the output comes out in the middle of an `<li>` element or `<table>`) so I am trying to find a way to embed my text in the middle of the post without breaking the current HTML.

Comment: Can you show us your desired output?

Comment: I am sorry but it's not clear - where is your PHP code that inserts text in the middle of `$str` ?

Comment: I think you are possibly approaching the problem incorrectly. Instead of inserting data into an existing string, only build the string when you know what needs to be inside it!

Comment: Add more detail by editing your question, NOT by adding comments. You can delete that comment as I have added it to your question

Comment: perhaps you can `preg_match_all` certain tags and put your text in between? like `$regex = '|<li>(.*)</li>|i'; preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$myText =  "testing  something";
$str = '<ul>
<li>Text</li>
<li>'. $myText.'</li>
</ul>';
```

**Here is a [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$myText%20=%20%22testing%20something%22;%5Cn$str%20=%20'%3Cul%3E%5Cn%3Cli%3EText%3C/li%3E%5Cn%3Cli%3E'.%20$myText.'%3C/li%3E%5Cn%3C/ul%3E';%5Cnecho%20$str;%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**